# Is there a way to put comments in the youtube-dl batch file?

Tags: youtube-dl

Let's suppose you want to make a long list of **Urls** but separated with a comment which

indicates what the **Urls** are about. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: @OrangeTux : http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/youtube-dl

Comment: Ok, it is clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`youtube -dl` supports only one url at each line in a url listed batch file. It will not read a url/line if it begins with a `#` or part of line after `#`. In that case your batch file should look like,

```
#comment 1
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foo
#commeent 2 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bar
```

You can comment like this also,

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foo #comment 1
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bar #comment 2
```

To download with such a batch file, use

```
youtube-dl --title --batch-file='/path/to/list.txt'
```

I assume `list.txt` contains the urls.

Answer (score 8):

Create your batch file with a url-list as usual. And comment a line by putting a `#` at the beginning of the line.

youtube-dl will not read that line.

Example: `url.txt`

```
#This is link 1
youtube.com/watch=url
#This is link 2 (blabla)
youtube.com/watch=url
```

Answer (score 5):

You can comment them just the way you'd comment them in bash. Just put a `#` before the comment. You can have a text file like this.

```
#This is a comment
# I hope people are not tasty
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWAF9PgDg2c #Would we eat each other if it were legal
#I love the moon
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bbgz4yY-xX0   #This is a comment too
```

Answer (score 4):

You can comment a line by putting a `#` or a `;` at the beginning of the line. Both will work.